# 2-d array not imputing correctly

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble getting the input for a 2-d array for an assignment. Basically I have to create a bug that crawls across the screen and writes an ASCII image of our name. We have to get the input from the text file so i figured the best course of action would be to create a 2-d array for each character in a file and have it determine what it does depending on what character is in each spot. However It always shows that the 2-d array has the same contents (shown below)

```
[[C@b1c5fa
```

Below is an example of the class, the tester class, and an example of the txt file. How can i get it to show the correct input?

#### Bug Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bug
{  

   private int startingPoint;
   private char mrBug;
    private char placeholder;
    private int postition;
    private int matrixLength;
    private int matrixRows;
    private String lineGet;
    private String txtFile;
    private char[][] Data = new char[3][];


   /**
      Constructs a computer class with title, days, time and room
   */
   public Bug(int initialPosition, char bug, String inputFile)
   {   
     startingPoint = initialPosition;
     mrBug = bug; 
      txtFile = inputFile;
   }


          public void matrixPrinter()
   {   
    for(int row = 0; row < Data.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < Data[row].length; col++)
            {
            System.out.print(Data[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

   }//End of matrixBuilder Method

    public void matrixBuilder()
   {   
        Scanner in = new Scanner(txtFile);
        matrixRows = 0;
        while (in.hasNextLine())
            {
                lineGet = in.next();
                matrixLength = lineGet.length();
                Data[matrixRows] = new char[matrixLength];
                for(int i = 0; i < matrixLength; i++)
                {
                    placeholder = lineGet.charAt(i);
                    Data[matrixRows][i]= placeholder;

                }//End of For
                matrixRows++;
            }//End of While
        in.close();
   }//End of matrixBuilder Method

    /**
      Gets the title
      @return the title
   */
    public void turn()
   {   
        //return title;

   }

   public void move()
   {   
      // your work here
   }

   /**
      Gets Postition
      @return the postition
   */
   public int getPostion()
   {   
    return postition;

   }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/g9LWFyXQ

#### Bug Tester

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BugTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        int start = 0;
       char bugSymbol = 'a';
        String inputFile = "peter.txt";
      Bug crawler1 = new Bug(start,bugSymbol,inputFile);
          crawler1.matrixBuilder();
        crawler1.matrixPrinter();

   }
}
```

#### Txt file:

```
/#****#****#*****#****#****#****#\
/#*##*#*######*###*####*##*#*##*#\
/#****#****###*###****#****####*#\
/#*####*######*###*####*#*#####*#\
/#*####****###*###****#*##*####*#\
```

Comment: To get code in: paste code, select code, click `{}`. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** One mistake is in your `matrixBuilder()` method.

You init Scanner, passing name of your file to the constructor:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(txtFile);
```

So it doesn't read the file contents when you call:

```
in.next();
```

The `lineGet` variable has the "peter.txt" value. It's obviously not what you want.

You need to init Scanner that way:

```
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(txtFile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // work up exception
    }
```

Or just

```
public void matrixBuilder() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(txtFile));
//...
}
```

**Second:**
The initial size of your Data array is incorrect:

```
private char[][] Data = new char[3][];
```

Your file "peter.txt" has at least **5** lines.
So, the initial size of your Data array should also be **5**.

After correcting this mistakes you should get the desired result.

*Hope this helps.*

**UPDATE:**

Complete working code:

*Bug.java*

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bug {
    private int startingPoint;
    private char mrBug;
    private char placeholder;
    private int postition;
    private int matrixLength;
    private int matrixRows;
    private String lineGet;
    private String txtFile;
    private char[][] Data = new char[5][];

    /**
    Constructs a computer class with title, days, time and room
     */
    public Bug(int initialPosition, char bug, String inputFile) {
        startingPoint = initialPosition;
        mrBug = bug;
        txtFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void matrixPrinter() {
        System.out.println("Data:");

        for (int row = 0; row < Data.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < Data[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(Data[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }//End of matrixBuilder Method

    public void matrixBuilder() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(txtFile));

        matrixRows = 0;
        // We should also check that the number of lines in the file 
        // doesn't exceed the Data array size.
        while (in.hasNextLine() && matrixRows < Data.length) {
            lineGet = in.next();
            System.out.println("line["+ matrixRows + "]:" + lineGet);
            matrixLength = lineGet.length();
            Data[matrixRows] = new char[matrixLength];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixLength; i++) {
                placeholder = lineGet.charAt(i);
                Data[matrixRows][i] = placeholder;

            }//End of For
            matrixRows++;
        }//End of While
        in.close();
    }//End of matrixBuilder Method

    /**
    Gets the title
    @return the title
     */
    public void turn() {
        //return title;
    }

    public void move() {
        // your work here
    }

    /**
    Gets Postition
    @return the postition
     */
    public int getPostion() {
        return postition;

    }
}
```

*BugTester.java*

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class BugTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int start = 0;
        char bugSymbol = 'a';
        String inputFile = "peter.txt";
        Bug crawler1 = new Bug(start, bugSymbol, inputFile);
        crawler1.matrixBuilder();
        crawler1.matrixPrinter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately I cannot use try/catch statements because "we have not used them and thus it is "plagiarizing" I had this happen and failed a project because i used recursion .... But i understand what the problem is and am trying to figure out how to work it without using try/catch statments....

Comment: You can use `throws` statement. Is this allowed?

Comment: even so with the try/catch i'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Bug.matrixBuilder(Bug.java:62)
 at BugTester.main(BugTester.java:23)` LINE 62 is the while statment. When i get nights like these it makes me want to change my  major.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to debug more in the morning! I'm to tired to probably even think straight.

Comment: @Pnchappy92 See my updated post. And more sleep if you are tired, of course!

Comment: Ok i just took a look at your code thats working but i'm getting an error 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: peter.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
 at Bug.matrixBuilder(Bug.java:38)
 at BugTester.main(BugTester.java:10)'

Comment: @Pnchappy92 Is it in your project folder?

Comment: Yeah it is. I have it in the same folder as the bug and bugTester

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5580/discussion-between-mockertim-and-pnchappy92)

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is an internal representation of the array object (its "signature").

If you want to print an array, you need to iterate over its elements. As it's 2D, just use two nested `for` loops.

Other problems:

- You're initializing your `Scanner` with a `String`, but what you want is to initialize it with a `File`. You'll need to create a new `File` object with your filename and pass that to the `Scanner` constructor, taking care of the possible exceptions
- Your file has four lines, but you `Data` array only has three lines. Either make your array bigger, or bail out of the input loop once you've read the number of lines the array can hold.

Comment: Ok, I change the printer method in the edit but now am getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Bug.matrixPrinter(Bug.java:40)
 at BugTester.main(BugTester.java:24)`

Comment: Which line is line 40? Did you change `main` at all?

Comment: Line 40 is 
`for(int col = 0; col < Data[row].length; col++)`
I changed the name of the txtfile but it is in the same folder and there under that name.

Comment: Updated my answer with two more hints. Please do some debugging yourself too - add print statements at various parts to check that your variables hold what you expect (or use a debugger).